# Two observer scenario

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

If I have two observers trying to determine the relative position of the same hydrogen electron and they have a device that allows them to make simultaneous measurements of the same electron (although they are located spatially 180 degrees apart). What would they theoretically observer if their measurements were simultaneous (i.e., at exactly the same time) and also a couple of seconds apart?

Comment: "Observing" an electron state necessarily means interacting with it (hitting it with a photon, or at the very least receiving a photon that the electron emits or interacts with). Not just "looking at it." So you cannot have one Observer do this in a way that does not affect the state for all Observers